# next() fails inside a <p> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jQuery code that is supposed to display tooltips (`<p>`) when the corresponding link (`<a>`) is hovered. For that I use the `next()` function to find the tooltip which is always placed right after the respective link.
Surprisingly, `next()` returns no elements when the link and the tooltip element are inside a `<p>` element. However, when I put those two in a `<div>`, it works fine - the next element is found.
I have created an entry on jsfiddle.net to help explain my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/zwEAZ/
The `console.log()` line in the code always logs 0 when hovering the second link.
I'm curious why it's behaving like that. Thanks in advance for any answers.

**Edit:** I'm posting the code here too (I'm assuming you have jquery-1.11.0.js in the same directory as the HTML document):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('.link').mouseenter(function(event) {
                    $(this).next().css({
                        left: event.pageX + 10 + 'px',
                        top: event.pageY + 10 + 'px'
                    }).stop().fadeIn(500);
                    console.log($(this).next().length);
                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).next().stop().fadeOut(250);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .tooltip {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #ccc;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Here it works:
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>

        <p>
            And here it doesn't...
            <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
            <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>
        </p>

        <div>
            But here it works again!
            <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
            <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `p` cannot contain another `p` element, it is an invalid HTML.

So if you inspect your html using browser development tools, you will see that the structure is modified as

```
<body>
    Here it works:
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>

    <p>
        And here it doesn't...
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    </p>
    <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>
    <p></p>

    <div>
        But here it works again!
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

now the `link` does not have a next sibling element

Answer (score 1):

P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

Go through the link http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1
which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Remove the `<p>` element from your second block of code

```
And here it doesn't...

<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
<p class="tooltip">Tooltip</p>
```

Comment: I have accepted the other answer as it was faster, but you have provided a useful link - thanks!